# Android Multiple Apps With Same Name in App List

Tags: android, loading

I have been loading apks onto my phone via eclipse and I notice that I have a bunch of apps in the list with the very same name.  What causes the launcher to list the application multiple times?  And how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the apps named the same, but they have different namespaces.

com.example.myDemoApp named AppDemo

com.example.DemoApp named AppDemo

com.wtf.SpinnerTest named AppDemo

That's my best guess.

Comment: Exactly. I think this can be the only reason.